# users created in mongo db is getting deleted after ~50 days (NO TTL specified)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm creating a user on a particular DB, it is getting deleted after ~50 days (db.getUsers() is returning empty array) I have not specified TTL.

Steps i have followed to create a user

1. mongo
2. use db_name
3. db.createUser({
      user: "user_id",
      pwd : "user_passowrd",
      roles: [
        {db:"db_name", role: "readWrite"}
   ]})

Mongo DB version 2.6.12

Let me know is there anything i'm missing here

Comment: The mongo server is on your local machine, or deployed somewhere ? Only users are deleted nothing else ? Is there an api that can delete the users from your application ?

Comment: Mongo is deployed in my local machine, yes only users are getting deleted other collections data are intact & no i have no api written to delete the user from app